# Higher OpenCV version?

Tags: python, opencv

I installed OpenCV (`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`) for Python.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
'4.0.0-pre'
```

The [documentation](https://opencv.org/releases.html) says the last version of OpenCV is 3.4.1 but I am getting a higher one. Any explanation for this?

Comment: 4.0.0 is the pre-release for opencv devs. I have no idea how you've downloaded it by default...

Comment: I would suggest cloning the most recent release https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.4.1

Comment: The people contributing to OpenCV. Actually developing the framework itself and implementing new algorithms etc. They will then do a "release" for all an sundry to use (you and me) and the most recent version is 3.4.1

Comment: [More details](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OE-4.-OpenCV-4) on what OpenCV 4.0 is

Comment: devs=developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `master` branch of `OpenCV` is `OpenCV 4`. They are planning to release it officially on *July 2018* but it's being developed in github and you can download it as a pre-release.

If you want you can download the `OpenCV 3` branch, which is `3.4.x`.

`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout origin/3.4`

This will get you the latest `OpenCV 3` branch. But if you want specifically `OpenCV 3.4.1` you can `checkout` with

`git checkout 3.4.1`